# AVAudioRecorder / AVAudioPlayer - append recording to file

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

Is there any way to record onto the end of an audio file? We can't just pause the recording instead of stopping it, because the user needs to be able to come back to the app later and add more audio to their recording. Currently, the audio is stored in CoreData as NSData. NSData's `AppendData` does not work because the resulting audio file still reports that it is only as long as the original data.

Another possibility would be taking the original audio file, along with the new one, and concatenate them into one audio file, if there's any way to do that.

Comment: Take a look at my code below. This is what I am using in a production app.

Comment: You can find my complete code for mearging: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49136633/2244094

Answer (score 8):

This can be done fairly easily using `AVMutableComposionTrack insertTimeRange:ofTrack:atTime:error`. The code is somewhat lengthy, but it's really just like 4 steps:

```
// Create a new audio track we can append to
AVMutableComposition* composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
AVMutableCompositionTrack* appendedAudioTrack = 
    [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
                             preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

// Grab the two audio tracks that need to be appended
AVURLAsset* originalAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]
    initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:originalAudioPath] options:nil];
AVURLAsset* newAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] 
    initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:newAudioPath] options:nil];

NSError* error = nil;

// Grab the first audio track and insert it into our appendedAudioTrack 
AVAssetTrack *originalTrack = [originalAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
CMTimeRange timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, originalAsset.duration);
[appendedAudioTrack insertTimeRange:timeRange 
                            ofTrack:[originalTrack objectAtIndex:0]
                             atTime:kCMTimeZero
                              error:&error];
if (error)
{
    // do something
    return;
}

// Grab the second audio track and insert it at the end of the first one
AVAssetTrack *newTrack = [newAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio]; 
timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, newAsset.duration);   
[appendedAudioTrack insertTimeRange:timeRange
                            ofTrack:[newTrack objectAtIndex:0]
                             atTime:originalAsset.duration
                              error:&error];

if (error)
{
    // do something
    return;
}

// Create a new audio file using the appendedAudioTrack      
AVAssetExportSession* exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession
                                       exportSessionWithAsset:composition
                                       presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
if (!exportSession)
{
    // do something
    return;
}


NSString* appendedAudioPath= @""; // make sure to fill this value in    
exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:appendedAudioPath];
exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A; 
[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

    // exported successfully?
    switch (exportSession.status)
    {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
            // you should now have the appended audio file
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    NSError* error = nil;

}];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can append two audio files by creating a `AVMutableCompositionTrack` after adding the two files and exporting the composition using `exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler` method of `AVAssetExportSession`.

Please refer below links for more details.

[AVAssetExportSession Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[Creating New Assets](http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_EditingAssets.html)

Hope this helps to solve your issue.

Comment: This answer, while not totally complete, definitely set me down the right path when I came up with this same issue.

Comment: I added complete code below, but it was this answer that pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @siddharth Where did you get the documentation @ disanji.net? It looks like a copy of the apple docs, but I don't see that section in the official apple docs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete code example but the Extended Audio File Services can help you concatenate two audio files. Search for Extended Audio File Services in Xcode or visit the link below.

[Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: Nothing in that documentation references appending audio files.

Comment: to be honest thats interesting ref, and its works if u do not want to concatenate to ready files, but want to write to existing file, and its awesome (like in apples recorder!)

Answer (score 1):

We had the same requirements for our app as the OP described, and ran into the same issues (i.e., the recording has to be stopped, instead of paused, if the user wants to listen to what she has recorded up to that point). Our app ([project's Github repo](https://github.com/society-for-the-blind/Access-News-Reader-iOS)) uses `AVQueuePlayer` for playback and a method similar to [kermitology's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009975/play-a-paused-avaudiorecorder-file#13438421) to concatenate the partial recordings, with some notable differences:

- implemented in **Swift**
- concatenates **multiple** recordings into one
- **no messing with tracks**

The rationale behind the last item is that simple recordings with `AVAudioRecorder` will have one track, and the main reason for this whole workaround is to concatenate those single tracks in the assets (see **Addendum 3**). So why not use `AVMutableComposition`'s `insertTimeRange` method instead, that takes an `AVAsset` instead of an `AVAssetTrack`?

Relevant parts: ([full code](https://github.com/society-for-the-blind/Access-News-Reader-iOS/blob/master/Access%20News%20Reader/RecordViewController.swift))

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class RecordViewController: UIViewController {

    /* App allows volunteers to record newspaper articles for the
       blind and print-impaired, hence the name.
    */
    var articleChunks = [AVURLAsset]()

    func concatChunks() {
        let composition = AVMutableComposition()

        /* `CMTimeRange` to store total duration and know when to
           insert subsequent assets.
        */
        var insertAt = CMTimeRange(start: kCMTimeZero, end: kCMTimeZero)

        repeat {
            let asset = self.articleChunks.removeFirst()

            let assetTimeRange = 
                CMTimeRange(start: kCMTimeZero, end: asset.duration)

            do {
                try composition.insertTimeRange(assetTimeRange, 
                                                of: asset, 
                                                at: insertAt.end)
            } catch {
                NSLog("Unable to compose asset track.")
            }

            let nextDuration = insertAt.duration + assetTimeRange.duration
            insertAt = CMTimeRange(start: kCMTimeZero, duration: nextDuration)
        } while self.articleChunks.count != 0

        let exportSession =
            AVAssetExportSession(
                asset:      composition,
                presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)

        exportSession?.outputFileType = AVFileType.m4a
        exportSession?.outputURL = /* create URL for output */
        // exportSession?.metadata = ...

        exportSession?.exportAsynchronously {

            switch exportSession?.status {
            case .unknown?: break
            case .waiting?: break
            case .exporting?: break
            case .completed?: break
            case .failed?: break
            case .cancelled?: break
            case .none: break
            }
        }

        /* Clean up (delete partial recordings, etc.) */
    }
```

This diagram helped me to get around what expects what and inherited from where. (`NSObject` is implicitly implied as superclass where there is no inheritance arrow.)

### [image]

**Addendum 1:** I had my reservations regarding the `switch` part instead of using KVO on `AVAssetExportSessionStatus`, but the docs are clear that `exportAsynchronously`'s callback block "is invoked when writing is complete or in the event of writing failure".

**Addendum 2:** Just in case if someone has issues with `AVQueuePlayer`: ['An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657462/an-avplayeritem-cannot-be-associated-with-more-than-one-instance-of-avplayer/49932017#49932017)

**Addendum 3:** Unless you are recording in stereo, but mobile devices have one input as far as I know. Also, using fancy audio mixing would also require the use of `AVCompositionTrack`. A good SO thread: Proper [AVAudioRecorder Settings for Recording Voice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149280/proper-avaudiorecorder-settings-for-recording-voice)