# Is it possible to mute AVAudioRecorder?

Tags: avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

I'd like the recording to continue, but with the audio muted. I'm **not** looking to pause the audio.

The alternative I have right now is pause the audio, throw in silence padding, continue recording, but if there was a simpler way of doing that, that would be great.

Comment: This might help: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue, After long research i got the way whatever already you thought.

Your are going on right path !

One developer given related answer
[AVAudioRecorder / AVAudioPlayer - append recording to file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9079506/5096868):

> You can append two audio files by creating a `AVMutableCompositionTrack` after adding the two files and exporting the composition using `exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler` method of `AVAssetExportSession`.
>
> Please refer below links for more details.
>
> [AVAssetExportSession Class Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9079506/5096868)
>
> [Creating New Assets](http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_EditingAssets.html)
>
> Hope this helps to solve your issue.