# Output audio settings when append one AAC file to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, aac, avassetexportsession

My app records two audio files one by one using AVAudioRecorder with audio parameters:

```
        NSDictionary *outputSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin], AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],AVEncoderBitDepthHintKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:128000], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                    nil];
```

I need append file2 at the end of file1. I'm using solution like [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13438421/824285) (appending two audio files by creating a AVMutableCompositionTrack after adding the two files and exporting the composition using `exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:` method of AVAssetExportSession).
It works, but I have two input files 128kbs 44.1kHz 16bit mono, and output file format is: 219.4kbs 44.1kHz 16bit stereo.

Is any way to configure output audio file parameters for AVAssetExportSession?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was found the solution: [**SDAVAssetExportSession**](https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession)

Comment: I am using the same library to export audios asynchronously but this export operation takes a lot of time for large audios. Is there a way to reduce that time.