# 'An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer'

Tags: ios, swift, avqueueplayer, avplayeritem

I know this question is all over Stack Overflow but still, most of them are old and not related with what I'm going to ask here.

So I've got an array with `AVPlayerItems` and an `AVQueuePlayer`. At first I set the AVQueuePlayer to play the array items:

```
func mediaPicker(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController!, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection!) {

    mediaItems = mediaItemCollection.items

    for thisItem in mediaItems as [MPMediaItem] {

        var itemUrl = thisItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as? NSURL
        var playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: itemUrl)
        mediaArray.append(playerItem)           

    }

    updateMetadata()

    audioPlayer = AVQueuePlayer(items: mediaArray)


    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

But, when the user, for example, adds a new Item or delete one, I try updating the player (the same way I set it in the first place), but it gives me the error. I want to know if there is any way around of it, or any solution. This is how the user deletes a song:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete{
            mediaArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
            audioPlayer = AVQueuePlayer(items: mediaArray) //here gives the error
        }
    }
```

I'm killing myself over this, so, if someone can help me, I would appreciate it.

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: That's not enough code. You need to show whole methods, not just single lines. Show also, what you do when the user adds or deletes an item.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're creating a new player object when you update the array of items with this line (in tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:),

```
audioPlayer = AVQueuePlayer(items: mediaArray)
```

It seems that the player items are still associated with the original player when you do this. You should be able to delete that line, to make it work properly. Inserting or deleting items from mediaArray should be enough to do what you want; you don't need to create a new player.

Comment: but *sadly* it isn't, it seems that when you first associate the array with the player, no matter what happens to the array, the player will still play the first given array. The funny thing is, if the mediaPicker is called again and the same musics are chosen, it plays just fine. I was wondering why Apple does it, it just doesn't seem necessary. Anyway, I think I'll have to change my approach, thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

The way I solved this issue is that I kept a reference to `AVAsset` objects in an array and then `map`ped it to `[AVPlayerItem]` (the type that `AVQUeuePlayer` init accepts).

To elaborate, we needed to make an audio recorder ([code on github](https://github.com/society-for-the-blind/Access-News-Reader-iOS)) that can be paused, so I used an `AVQueuePlayer`, but ran into the same issues as the OP, and the only clean solution is to recreate this player object with a new array.

The relevant code in **Swift** 4.1:

```
class RecordViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder?

    var audioChunks = [AVURLAsset]()
    var queuePlayer:  AVQueuePlayer?

// irrelevant code omitted

    func stopRecorder() {
        self.audioRecorder?.stop()
        let assetURL  = self.audioRecorder!.url

        self.audioRecorder = nil

        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: assetURL)
        self.audioChunks.append(asset)

        let assetKeys = ["playable"]
        let playerItems = self.audioChunks.map {
            AVPlayerItem(asset: $0, automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: assetKeys)
        }

        self.queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer(items: playerItems)
        self.queuePlayer?.actionAtItemEnd = .advance
    }

    func startPlayer() {
        self.queuePlayer?.play()
    }

    func stopPlayer() {
        self.queuePlayer?.pause()
        self.queuePlayer = nil
    }
}
```

(In the end, [`AVAssetExportSession` is used to stitch the chunks of audio back together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009975/play-a-paused-avaudiorecorder-file#13438421), so storing `AVAsset`s insead of `AVPlayerItem`s was even more beneficial in the end.)

Answer (score 3):

Using this code solved the problem for me:

> ```
> player?.pause()                     
> let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: myAsset) 
> player = nil 
> player = AVPlayer()
> player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
> ```

Instead of:

> ```
> player?.pause()                     
> player = nil 
> player = AVPlayer()
> player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: availablePlayerItem) 
> //availablePlayerItem is a playerItem which has been created before and played once with this AVPlayer
> ```

Note:
In both codes, the "player" is a global variable in my class which is:

> var player : AVPlayer? = nil

Answer (score 2):

From [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVQueuePlayer/insertItem:afterItem:):

Before add an item:

> `canInsertItem(_:afterItem:)`
>
> Returns a Boolean value that indicates
>   whether a given player item can be inserted into the player’s queue.
>
> ```
> func canInsertItem(_ item: AVPlayerItem!, afterItem afterItem: AVPlayerItem!) -> Bool
> ```

Adding an Item:

> ```
> insertItem(_:afterItem:)
> ```
>
> Places given player item after a specified item in the queue.
>
> ```
>  func insertItem(_ item: AVPlayerItem!, afterItem afterItem: AVPlayerItem!)
> ```

Removing an Item:

> `removeItem(_:)`
>
> Removes a given player item from the queue.
>
> `func removeItem(_ item: AVPlayerItem!)`

Comment: yeah, I know that, but, if I try to add an item that has already been played, it gives the error, for example

Comment: You need to check if you can insert before you do so, I add it to the answer I hope it helps you

Comment: I already knew that too, it's kinda of an unsolvable problem thanks to Apple. But thanks anyway

Comment: Add a bit more of your code I am sure we will be able to help you if we can see a bit more of what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

It is required to check that the player item can be inserted into the player’s queue. Then add, remove or replace the player item based on the conditions as below:

```
if player.canInsert(playerItem, after: nil) == true {

            player = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

        } else {

            player.remove(self.playerItem)

            player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I initially initialized an AVPlayerItem inside a cell and added it to an AVPlayer (also inside the cell). I later presented a new vc and passed over that same cell's AVPlayerItem to a different AVPlayer inside the new vc and got a crash. To fix it I just made a copy of the playerItem using `.copy() as? AVPlayerItem`. A copy gives the new copy a different memory address from the original.

cell:

```
var cellPlayer: AVPlayer?
var cellsPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem?

cellsPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: AVAsset(url: url)) // cellsPlayerItem's memory address 0x1111111
cellPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: cellsPlayerItem!)
```

presented vc:

```
var vcPlayer: AVPlayer?

let playerItemCopy = cellsPlayerItem.copy() as? AVPlayerItem // playerItemCopy's memory address 0x2222222
let vcPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItemCopy)
```