# iOS Core Audio - Can I set the preferred hardware buffer size higher than 4096

Tags: ios, core-audio

It seems I can't set the preferred hardware buffer size higher than 4096 frames, does anyone know if this is possible? If not, is there documentation asserting this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149280/proper-avaudiorecorder-settings-for-recording-voice

Comment: That question has a lot of useful information but I can't find an answer there

Comment: The question and title are likely seriously mis-worded.  The preferred audio buffer size maximum might be 4096.  But this size is independent of the sample rate, which is likely to be something like 8, 44.1 or 48 kHz.